# Why Local Users and Groups is missing in Computer Management on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows, windows-10, winrm

I'm using Windows 10 Home.

While troubleshooting some issue with WinRM, I figured out "Local Users and Groups" item is missing in my System Tools.

Computer Management >> System Tools >> "Local Users and Groups" missing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Windows 10 Home Edition does not have Local Users and Groups option so that is the reason you aren't able to see that in Computer Management.

You can use User Accounts by pressing `Window`+`R`, typing `netplwiz` and pressing OK [as described here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6917-account-type-change-windows-10-a.html#option3).

Comment: To be precise: there are always local users and groups, just the *Local Users and Groups console snap-in* is disabled in the Home edition, for commercial reasons.

Comment: Which versions of Windows have Local Users and Groups?

Comment: @andrewcockerham all except home I believe